# Problem inserting string into array

Tags: php, arrays, string, implode, generated

i'm trying to insert an implode generated string to an array that then later be used for json implementation

the implode generated string is look like this

```
'id' => $this->_SqlResult[0],'UserId' => $this->_SqlResult[1],'Msg' => $this->_SqlResult[2],'MsgStamp' => $this->_SqlResult[3]
```

i would like to used it in this code

```
$this->_JsonArr[]=array($Generated string);
```

to achieve something like this

```
 $this->_JsonArr[]=array('id' => $this->_SqlResult[0],'UserId' => $this->_SqlResult[1],'Msg' => $this->_SqlResult[2],'MsgStamp' => $this->_SqlResult[3]);
```

instead i got something like this

```
 $this->_JsonArr[]=array(" 'id' => $this->_SqlResult[0],'UserId' => $this->_SqlResult[1],'Msg' => $this->_SqlResult[2],'MsgStamp' => $this->_SqlResult[3]");
```

seem like generated string is treated as one element as key and value pair.
obviously i can get expected output from mysql because of this, can anybody help me with this

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to implode anything? Just pass the array:

```
$this->_JsonArr[] = your-non-imploded-array-here;
```

I think a full solution to what you want to do is something like this (i.e., the third code box in your question):

```
$row = array(
  'id' => $this->_SqlResult[0],
  'UserId' => $this->_SqlResult[1],
  'Msg' => $this->_SqlResult[2],
  'MsgStamp' => $this->_SqlResult[3]
);
$this->_JsonArr[] = $row;
```

Comment: I think (just wild guess)  OP got confused when serving data in json (hence imploding the array into string). So, as addition @zul don't forget to `echo json_encode($this->_JsonArr)` to output the string with data.

Answer (score 0):

> $this->_JsonArr[]=array($Generated
>   string);

Looks like you want use arrays keys and values, but as I see you put into array plain string with expectation that array parse your plain string in format: keys => values.

You can try create array like below:

> $this->_JsonArr[ $Generated_key ] = array( $Generated_value );

(Please correct me if I wrong understand your question).